# Proof that the existence of the limit of a sum of random variables belongs to the tail $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability

Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent random variables, and let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. For each $i$, let $\mathcal{G}_i=\sigma X$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_i$. Define $\mathcal{T}_n=\sigma(\cup_{m>n}\mathcal{G}_n)$: we can think about it as the information generated by all the "trials" after $n$. Lastly, define $\mathcal{T}=\cap_{n=1}^\infty\mathcal{T}_n$ : we can think about it as the information about the remote future.

Prove that the event $\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_n S_n(\omega)$  exists in $\overline{\Bbb{R}} \}$ $\in \mathcal{T}$.

$\textbf{My attempt}$

Considering that $\{\exists \lim_nS_n \in \overline{\Bbb{R}} \} = \{\limsup S_n = \liminf S_n\}$, i.e. $\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_m \sup_{n>m} S_n(\omega) = \lim_m \inf_{n>m} S_n(\omega)\}$, I started from spelling out

$\sup_{n>m} \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}X_i(\omega) = \sup_{n>m}(\sum_{i=1}^mX_i(\omega) + \sum_{j=m+1}^{+\infty}X_j(\omega)) = \sum_{i=1}^mX_i(\omega) + \sup_{n>m}\sum_{j=m+1}^{+\infty}X_j(\omega)$

and similarly

$\inf_{n>m} \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}X_i(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^mX_i(\omega) + \inf_{n>m}\sum_{j=m+1}^{+\infty}X_j(\omega)$

then

$\lim_m\inf_{n>m} \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}X_i(\omega) = \lim_m\sup_{n>m} \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}X_i(\omega) \iff \lim_m\inf_{n>m} \sum_{i=m+1}^{+\infty}X_i(\omega) = \lim_m\sup_{n>m} \sum_{i=m+1}^{+\infty}X_i(\omega)$

which is equivalent to

$\limsup_n X_n(\omega)=\liminf_n X_n(\omega)$, i.e. $\exists \lim_n X_n(\omega)$.

But $\{\exists \lim_n X_n\} \in \mathcal{T}_n$ $\forall n\ge1$, i.e. $\{\exists \lim_n X_n\} \in \mathcal{T}$

I don't know if some of the steps above are wrong or incomplete. Any help would be so much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You may need to clarify the meaning of $\lim_n S_n(\omega)$ exists. Whether it exists in $\mathbb{R}$ or in the extended real line $[-\infty,\infty]$. I interpreted it as exists in $\mathbb{R}$ and posted my solution. Such solution needs modification if you mean "exists in the extended real line".

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the limit is meant to be in the extended real line. At first I didn't specify it because the textbook doesn't, I've updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one wants to argue using limsup and liminf, we may work in the
following way.

Claim: $\limsup_{n}S_{n}$ is $\mathcal{T}$-measurable.

Proof: Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Let $\xi=\limsup_{n}S_{n}$.
We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\xi & = & \inf_{n\geq1}\sup_{k\geq n}S_{k}\\
 & = & \inf_{n>N}\sup_{k\geq n}S_{k}
\end{eqnarray*}
by observing that for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $\left(\sup_{k\geq n}S_{k}(\omega)\right)_{n}$
is a decreasing sequence of numbers in $[-\infty,\infty]$. For each
$n>N$, $\sup_{k\geq n}S_{k}$ is $\mathcal{T}_{N}$-measurable. (For
example, let $a\in[-\infty,\infty]$ be arbitrary, then $\left[\sup_{k\geq n}S_{k}\leq a\right]=\cap_{k\geq n}\left[S_{k}\leq a\right]$,
which is an element in $\mathcal{T}_{N}$). Therefore, $\inf_{n>N}\sup_{k\geq n}S_{k}$
is $\mathcal{T}_{N}$-measurable. That is, $\xi$ is $\mathcal{T}_{N}$-measurable.
Since $N$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\xi$ is $\cap_{N}\mathcal{T}_{N}=\mathcal{T}$-measurable.
QED

Similarly, we can prove that $\liminf_{n}S_{n}$ is $\mathcal{T}$-measurable.
Denote $\eta=\liminf_{n}S_{n}$. We have that $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\lim_{n}S_{n}(\omega)\mbox{ exists in }[-\infty,\infty]\}=\left[\xi=\eta\right]\in\mathcal{T}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{n}(\omega)\mbox{ exists and is finite.}\}$.
Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. We have
that $A=\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\cup_{l=N}^{\infty}\cap_{n>m\geq l}\{\omega\mid\left|S_{m}(\omega)-S_{n}(\omega)\right|<\frac{1}{k}\}$ because for each $\omega\in\Omega$, $\omega\in A$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(S_{n}(\omega))$
is a Cauchy sequence.
Clearly, $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\cup_{l=N}^{\infty}\cap_{n>m\geq l}\{\omega\mid\left|S_{m}(\omega)-S_{n}(\omega)\right|<\frac{1}{k}\}\in\mathcal{T}_{N}$
because if $n>m\geq l\geq N$ , $S_{n}-S_{m}=X_{m+1}+X_{m+2}+\ldots+X_{n}$
which is $\mathcal{T}_{N}$-measurable. Since $N$ is arbitrary, it
follows that $A\in\cap_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{T}_{N}=\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Do you think my own solution is wrong?

Comment: No. I have not read it.